# How to disable direct access to application server that sits behind nginx?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, kibana

I have `Kibana` application working at `http://myip:5601`

I would like it to work through `nginx` at `http://mydomain.ru`

I have enough knowledge to configure `proxy_pass` from `nginx` to `Kibana`. The only thing I don't know is how to disable access to `Kibana` directly through `http://myip:5601`.

Comment: That's not really an nginx question. You have to limit access on your kibana host - either through iptables, hosts.deny/hosts.allow, or another nginx instance on that hosts that connects to the (only via localhost accessible) Kibana installation. In some way, you have to whitelist the IP of the nginx frontend server. There are many ways...

Comment: If your kibana application and your ngnix proxy is running on the same host, the obvious thing is to have your kibana application only listen on localhost

Comment: Thanks, @nos, it is true. Both nginx and kibana are running on the same host. I'm not sure how to make Kibana listen on localhost only. Should I look into Kibana configs? Or there is another way to enable localhost only?

Comment: @AlexSmolov I don't really know anything about kibana, but the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kibana-server-properties.html) says you can configure the server.host, so set that to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this on 4.1 Kibana (refer to docs for changed properties for 4.2 onwards)

Change the host: "0.0.0.0" to host: "localhost" . This will make sure kibana binds to localhost only and will not serve to anyone outside of localhost request and then have nginx proxy kibana requests.